# How to call a Ruby class without namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

There are two classes in Rails application: one with namespace, other - without. Both have the same name.

How to call a class without namespace from within a namespace?

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
end

module MyNamespace
    class MyClass < Base
    end

    class OtherClass < Base
       def some_method
           #Intend to create MyClass model, but MyNamespace::MyClass is created
           mobj = MyClass
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To break out of the current namespace, just write:

```
mobj = ::MyClass
```